# Need to aceess master layout controls from a view in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC web application with master layout and views based on that layout.And I need to display some text in a label which is in the master layout.

And my javascript function is in the child view.

here is my master page.

```
<body onload="setInterval('LayOutHandler.DiplayClock()', 1000);">


       <div id="notify">
                    @Html.Label("hi", new { id="lblnotify"})
                </div>

</body
```

And here is my javascript function in the view..

```
 getCustomerDetails: function (customerPhoneNumber) {

            $("#lblnotify").val("calling");
        },
```

don't mind the javascript function, its a call back function which fires from signalr.And it works fine.The issue is I can't change the text of the  **lblnotify** from this function. It identifies the lable object, but text is not changing...

How can I slove this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label is rendered in html as:

```
<label id="lblnotify">hi</label>
```

and for changing text between its tags, you need to use `text()`:

```
$("#lblnotify").text("calling");
```